# How to sync domain user desktops to be accessed from anywhere

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7

I am trying to understand if there is a way to have domain user that has a normal workstations that is there has there outlook installed there office etc installed to access that stuff from a different computer on the domain. I know remote desktop can do this but most people here are not technology capable of connecting to a remote desktop. I really dont know what im looking for and am new to domains. This would be like a new person comes in they get a user setup and then are being trained on there account but on a workstation that is with the manager so would need to access there email or there quickbooks but from the other pc.

Brent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote desktop may work yet. You don't need to be technical to double-click an icon. You can create saved remote desktop connections that, upon double-clicking, either immediately connect to the remote computer with saved credentials or simply ask for a username and password.

Another option is [Roaming Profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaming_user_profile). A user has their files and other profile information roam with them no matter the computer that they log onto. Note that *applications* do not roam with the person, on the files and settings in their profile folder.

Comment: Ok thank you I will reseach those 2 options and see what will fit better. Thank You